# Как с помощью Twill нажать кнопку?

Tags: python, html

Есть 1 кнопка такого рода:
    <a href="#" class="btn large editfile" data-modal-link="#editfile" id="editfile_link" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'files', 'edit', location.href]);">Править</a>
Как её "нажать" средствами Twill / Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом нет смысла (и, следовательно, нет такой команды), так как Twill не поддерживает JavaScript. Если вам нужно засабмитить форму, используйте `submit [<n>]`, где `n` - номер кнопки отправки формы (в случае, если не указана, используется последняя из найденных кнопок).